# PHP memory leak from a information schema query

Tags: php, mysql, memory-leaks, laravel-4

I have an application where I'm querying a large table of zip code information. The table has 41143 rows of information. The application is built in Laravel and I'm using the `DB` facade to do the selects.

I'm building a paging structure so I wanted to be able to get the total number of rows so I can determine how many pages there would be given the number of output rows the user wants to see.

When I tried my first query, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM zipCodes` I got a php memory error (not ultra surprising).

I then changed my query to the following:

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "zipCodes"
```

Considering the `TABLE_ROWS` column in the information schema is just one number I thought that it wouldn't take any time at all to pull, but I get the same error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) ...

Why would this the query against the information_schema table cause a memory leak?

I should also add that:

- I tried selecting a number of things from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table with the query and got the same error
- When I try the same querying from the DB facade structure but use the zipCodes table directly (and limit the query) I don't receive a memory error.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` generating a memory error *should* surprise you, because the database is doing all the counting and returning a tiny result to php... that is what should happen *in both cases.* It sounds as if you've got a runaway loop or something else has your memory usage already sky-high... but this (what you're experiencing with this query) is only likely to be a side-effect of the real problem.

Comment: Ah! It was definitely my memory being sky high. I didn't think about the fact that I was temporarily serving the site using the built in php development server. Of course my php memory was super high. I stopped the development server and moved it to a regular apache webroot and the query worked fine. Thanks for the point in the right direction and the point that mysql is doing the counting and not php (long day of coding == the brain not firing as well as it could be :/ )